# ASP:Gridview checkbox column with paging is not showing which checkbox is checked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In a Asp:GridView (ASP.NET/VB), I have a column of checkbox:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" " ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" HeaderStyle-Width="3%" ItemStyle-Width="3%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="box_border table_title" ItemStyle-CssClass="box_border ">
    <ItemTemplate>               
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHaktzaa"  runat="server"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And I also have paging in the grid:

```
<table id="pager" align="center" dir="ltr" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td id="last" class="last" runat="server" clientidmode="Static"></td>
<td id="next" runat="server" tooltip="הבא" class="next" clientidmode="Static"></td>
<td>
<input id="pageNum" runat="server" class="pagedisplay" clientidmode="Static" />
</td>
<td class="prev" clientidmode="Static"></td>
<td class="first" clientidmode="Static"></td>
<td>
<select id="numOfRec" runat="server" class="pagesize" clientidmode="Static">
<option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In code-behind when I iterate over these grid rows, and programmatically access the CheckBox control, and then consult its `Checked` property to determine whether the it's been selected, it only works with the current page of the grid. It does not consider the other pages.

The rows on the other pages always return false for checked.

This is the iteration loop:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In gvBakashot.Rows
   Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("chkHaktzaa")
   If cb IsNot Nothing And cb.Checked Then
      lst.Add(count)
   End If
   count = count + 1
Next
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well of course when you re-load the page and re-load the WHOLE grid to a new page of data, a un-bound check box is not going to hold or remember its value.

What this means is that you need to get/grab/save the check box into some colleciton that persists, and then on grid display/re-load, you have to then re-set the check boxes.

In other words, if you jump to a new page, then you are doing a 100% whole new re-load of the page and the grid - and of course some old preivous grid loaded will not remember what check boxes were checked.

So, you need to manage (save) the checked boxes. So the only question then becomes do we do this DURING each check box checked, or when you page - really the ONLY question we need to answer here.

You don't mention how many rows you show - but the grid for a given page will persist (assuming you written this correctly and DO NOT re-load the grid when a page post-back occurs. In other words, your page load event ONLY loads the grid on first page load (PostBack = false). Assuming this critical design issue? (which ALL and EVERY page you write BETTER follow this rule!!!).

Ok, then, I suggest this:

Here is the markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" Width="50%" AllowPaging="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"               />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ckSel" runat="server" 
                            Checked='<%# MyChecked(Eval("ID")) %>'
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnCheckedChanged="ckSel_CheckedChanged"
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

And our code to fill the grid is this:

```
Dim MyCheckList As New List(Of Integer)
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
        ViewState("CheckList") = MyCheckList
    Else
        MyCheckList = ViewState("CheckList")
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName", conn)

            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function MyChecked(ID As Integer) As Boolean

    Return MyCheckList.Contains(ID)

End Function
```

Now HOW we persist that "list" to the page.

Now, it is a simple matter to write the code for the check box above.

And that code is easy, and this:

```
Protected Sub ckSel_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' user click on check box
    Dim ckSel As CheckBox = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = ckSel.Parent.Parent
    Dim PKID As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    If ckSel.Checked Then
        ' add to our collection
        MyCheckList.Add(PKID)
    Else
        ' remove from check list
        MyCheckList.Remove(PKID)
    End If

End Sub
```

And the results are now this:

[image]

So, now mylist will maintain, and keep a list of the choices you made.

You can then say do this:

```
    ' get selected data
    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Dim strWhere As String = String.Join(",", MyCheckList.ToArray())
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE ID IN(" & strWhere & ") ORDER BY HotelName"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    ' now do whatever, 

    For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstData.Rows
        ' do whatever
    Next
```

So you can then pass the PK id list.

Note ALSO very careful in above, we did not show, or even have to display the PK value from each row - we used DataKeys for that. This is great for MANY reasons, but significant is we DO NOT expose the PK database id's in the grid or markup. this is really nice for reasons of security, and it also  meant we did not include the PK ID in the grids markup either, nor did we even have to hide the pk column - that's what DataKeys feature is for.

Edit: To be fair? I did use Eval("ID") - and did expose the ID in the GV - but I actually did not have to do this (code was shorter).